# How do I sort a doubly-linked list in ascending order?

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to perform an insertion-sort function on a doubly linked list in the C programming language. When I run the code with this function on a doubly linked list of
**1<-->3<-->7<-->4<-->9** I get a sorted output. However, When I run this code on a doubly linked list of **5<-->3<-->7<-->4<-->9** I get a blank output (and yes it still compiles and runs).

I cannot figure out why it is returning a blank output when the first node has greater value than the second. I would guess it has something to do with my if statement?

```
void insertion_sort_increasing(struct List *list)
{
    struct Node *current_node = list->head; //initialize current_node
    struct Node *tempA;
    struct Node *tempB;
    struct Node *tempC;
    struct Node *tempD;

    if (current_node == NULL) {
        printf("Empty List.");
    } else {
        current_node = current_node->next;
        while (current_node != NULL) { //iterates doubly linked list
            if (current_node->prev->StudentID > current_node->StudentID) {
                tempA = current_node; //(3 in this case)
                tempB = current_node->prev->prev; //(NULL in this case)
                tempC = tempA->next->prev;
                tempD = tempB->next;

                tempA->next->prev = tempA->prev; // 5<--7
                tempB->next->prev = tempC;       // 3<--5
                tempB->next = tempA->prev->next; // NULL-->3
                tempA->prev->next = tempA->next; // 5-->7
                tempA->next = tempD;             // 3-->5
                tempA->prev = tempD->prev;       // NULL<--3
                if (tempB == NULL) {
                    list->head = tempB->next;    // 3 = head
                }
            }
            current_node = current_node->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve] and pick a language. What's right for C++ is not right for C and vice-a-versa.

Comment: Please elaborate more and explain what does returning blank mean? how did you test the code? please also add that code.

Comment: BTW: I don't think that's an insertion sort. There's a blizzard of node pointers there, but I don't think I see an output list.

Comment: And I would note that it's not possible to sort a non-trivially unsorted list with just one loop.  What you have to do is pop items off the input list, and insert them into their proper position in the output list. So you have an outer loop for popping each node, and an inner loop (best to put it in an `SortedInsert()` function) that iterates over the output loop to find the correct position for the node it just popped off the input list.

Comment: When `tempB` is NULL, `tempB->next` may crash the program.

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to use your debugger. Or insert some `printf()`s in your code. Additionally jwdonahue's answer is good advice.

Comment: (a very efficient way is to simply create an array from your list, `qsort()` the array and then repopulate your list -- you traverse the list exactly twice -- while attempting to sort your list in-place your worst case is an order of magnitude worse)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you perform a single scan through the list, swapping adjacent nodes that are out of order. This loop does not handle the case of a node that should move left by more than one position.
- the code crashes if `tempB` is null, ie: if the 2 initial nodes of the list should be swapped.
- `list->head` should be updated if the first node changes.
- the temporary variable names are confusing, esp `tempC` that is equal to `tempA`, and the initial order is not `tempA` -> `tempB` -> `tempC` -> `tempD`.
- for insertion sort, you should move the current node to its position among the nodes sorted so far and skip to the next node until you reach the end of the list.

Here is a modified version:

```
void insertion_sort_increasing(struct List *list)
{
    struct Node *current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node != NULL) {
        struct Node *next = current_node->next;
        while (current_node->prev && current_node->prev->StudentID > current_node->StudentID) {
            // swap current_node and its predecessor (tempC and tempB)
            struct Node *tempA = current_node->prev->prev;
            struct Node *tempB = current_node->prev;
            struct Node *tempC = current_node;
            struct Node *tempD = current_node->next;

            if (tempA) {
                tempA->next = tempC;
            } else {
                list->head = tempC;
            }
            tempC->prev = tempA;
            tempC->next = tempB;
            tempB->prev = tempC;
            tempB->next = tempD;
            if (tempD) {
                tempD->prev = tempB;
            } else {
                list->tail = tempB;
            }
        }
        current_node = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn to separate concerns in your code. An insertion sort takes an input list or array and returns an output list or array. So to start with, you need a function that either takes a `List**` and returns `void`, or it takes a `List*` and returns a `List*`. Logically you need to do three things correctly, 1) iterate over the input list, 2) Remove a node from the input list without breaking 1, 3) insert into the output list at the correct position for the sort order. That amounts to three functions.

```
List *InsertionSort(List * pList) {...}
List *SortedInsert(List *pList, List *pNode) {...}
List *Remove(List *pNode) {...}
```

`InsertionSort` just loops over the it's input, calling `Remove`, without loosing track of the head or tail pointer, depending on which way you're moving through the list, and then calls `SortedInsert` with the node it just removed from the head or tail of the pList. `SortedInsert` then iterates through `pList` looking for the correct place to insert `pNode` and then returns the new head of the list, which might just be `pNode`.

It's just easier to think about one operation at a time, and the code you write will be simpler and easier to understand and debug. In fact, you can test `SortedInsert` first, to make sure it's working, then test `Remove`, and then move on to to `InsertionSort`. You'll need to learn how to use your debugger and make yourself familiar with stepping through your code and checking the state of your variables. A fourth function, `PrintList` is probably on order here as well.

I am not going to write a bunch of code or be really explicit about the algorithm details, because you can get that with an SO or Google search, and this seems like an obvious homework assignment.